# Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

I am coding this in react.js and I really have no idea what is going on. I am using unirest to make the api call but the fetch isn't working so to me it seems I am doing something wrong in the fetch statement.

```js
unirest.get("https://heisenbug-la-liga-live-scores-v1.p.mashape.com/api/laliga/table")
.header("X-Mashape-Key", "Lzrv6ktkq3mshGiQJrPDa9cBxcDGp1Vcdncjsn1DweG4jU5ref")
.header("Accept", "application/json")
.end(function (result) {
  console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
});

fetch(unirest)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();

  })
  .then((json) => {
    console.log(json)

    this.setState({
      record: json.records[0]

    });
  })
```

Comment: that API is possibly not returning valid JSON - (looks like html) - what your code does not have is any form of error handling (hence the unhandled rejection) ... add a `.catch(err =>....` that way you handle any rejection ... check the developer tools network tab, look at the response you get from that API and check it is valid JSON, if not, the response may indicate where you went wrong

Comment: I normally see this when the API is sending back an error page because the endpoint is not correct, authorization is not valid, or some other reason that's keeping you from getting the where you actually want to go.

Comment: Having checked your request, however, it seems the response is valid JSON - so ... no idea why you are getting the error - though, not sure what all that `unirest.get` stuff is to be honest ... I just used a `fetch` - `fetch("https://heisenbug-la-liga-live-scores-v1.p.mashape.com/api/laliga/table", {headers:{"X-Mashape-Key": "Lzrv6ktkq3mshGiQJrPDa9cBxcDGp1Vcdncjsn1DweG4jU5ref", "Accept": "application/json"}}).then(r => r.json()).then(console.log)`

Comment: Unirest is this http://unirest.io/nodejs.html it is way to make api calls. In this case the api I am using is from mashape so this was the best way to make the request

Comment: Why do you need both fetch and unirest? They essentially do the same thing.